# mysql query needs to be altered

Tags: mysql

Here is the query which needs to be altered. I have attached the output of the screen. Here i need only the results where **maxBuy is less than or equal to totalDealsBought**. How should i change in this query for the O/P.

**EDIT : ONE more small alter to be done in this query.
That is i need to display the result in following format:**

**1. Where totalDealsBought should be less than maxBuy should display FIRST.**

How can this be done?

```
SELECT d.id, d.dealTitle, d.expiryDate, d.dealMainImage, d.actualPrice, d.discount, d.offerValue, d.maxBuy, sum( sc.quantity ) AS totalDealsBought
    FROM deal AS d
    LEFT JOIN shoppingcart AS sc ON sc.dealID = d.id
    WHERE CURDATE( ) != d.startDate
    AND d.startDate < CURDATE( )
    AND d.status = 'Active'
    AND d.cities = 'chennai'
    AND sc.paymentStatus = 'paid'
    GROUP BY d.id
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried with

```
GROUP BY d.id
HAVING d.maxBuy <= sum(sc.quantity)
```

Comment: Good, but he's already aliased SUM(sc.quantity) to totalDealsBought.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following line
`HAVING maxBuy <= totalDealsBought` 
to the end of the query.